# How to preserve return chariot with regex in vscode extension?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writting an OCaml code style extension in VSCode.
I would format correctly the separator `:`.

My code works fine for my test except for new line

```
let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;)

// text1 for test azae:aaz azea: zae azeaz :zae eaz:  zeazea azeaz  :zae
// text2 for test azae:aaz azea:    zae azeaz   :zae eaz:       zeazea azeaz        :zae
// text3 for test azae:
// aze

let selection = editor.selection
let text = editor.document.getText(selection)
textreg = text.replace(new RegExp(/(\s|\t)*[\:](\s|\t)*/g,'gi'),": ")
editor.edit(builder => builder.replace(selection, textreg));
```

I obtain:

```
text3 for test azae:    // aze
```

and I hope to have:

```
text3 for test azae:
// aze
```

How can I do that?

Edit :
Thanks for the comment, I realized my misinterpretation of \s

To write my expected result:

```
text1 for test azae:aaz azea: zae azeaz :zae eaz:  zeazea azeaz  :zae
text2 for test azae:aaz azea:   zae azeaz   :zae eaz:       zeazea azeaz        :zae
text3 for test azae:
aze
```

should become

```
text1 for test azae: aaz azea: zae azeaz: zae eaz: zeazea azeaz: zae
text2 for test azae: aaz azea: zae azeaz: zae eaz: zeazea azeaz: zae
text3 for test azae:
aze
```

Like @Yunnosch said I need a \s whithout \n

I try:

```
textreg = text.replace(new RegExp(/(\s)*[\:]([\s^\n])*/g,''),": ")
```

but in this case

```
azae:aaz
```

becomes

```
azae:
```

Comment: I think you can use this `\s*:\s*` and replace with a newline https://regex101.com/r/VoTvg5/1 `\s` also matches `\t` so you could shorten that to `\s*` only.

Comment: Looks like you don't want your `\s` to match newlines. Just for finding out, try to replace the `\s` with an explicit list of whitespaces you want processed, leaving out the `\n`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Wouldn't that introduce a newline unconditionally? I understand that to be undesired, especially in all other test cases which don't have newline to begin with.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think you are right, let me remove that comment.

Comment: Please explain what the purpose of your regex is. Should it preserve newlines (as the title says) and replace all other occurences of whitespace around a `:` with a single trailing blank?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Let OP clarify...

Comment: First thank for the comment.
I realize mymiss interpretation of \s
Second yes @Yunnosch i want remove all white space or tab pr etc around ":" and write ": "

Comment: I try textreg = text.replace(new RegExp(/(\s)*[\:]([\s^\n])*/g,''),": ") 
It works fine for new line but no more for aze:azeza the second text disapear

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all the information which currently hides in comments.

Comment: I think the replace command should look like `text.replace(/[\s\n]*:[\s\n]*/g, ": ")`.

Comment: Or perhaps match only a space or tab https://regex101.com/r/o3TJeD/2 for example `textreg = text.replace(new RegExp(/[ \t]*:[ \t]*/g,'gi'),": ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `(\s)*[\:]([\s^\n])*` you use a character class `[\s^\n]` which will match a whitespace char, a `^` and a newline. (Note that `\s` itself also matches a newline)

This way the newline after `text3 for test azae:` will also be matched and you get `text3 for test azae: aze`

It seems that you want to remove spaces or tabs before and after the colon and get a colon followed by a single space in return.

In that case you could use:

```
[ \t]*:[ \t]*
```

And as the replacement use a colon followed by a single space `:`

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MUhcXR/1)

Your code might look like this (you can omit the `/i` flag)

```
text.replace(/[ \t]*:[ \t]*/g, ": ")
```

**Note** that if you intended to use `\s` and wanted to exclude a newline from it using `^` to negate it, you could place that at the start of the character class and use [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/QOcGPR/1) instead where `\S` will match a non whitespace char:

`[^\S\n\r]*:[^\S\n\r]*`

Comment: Thanks  ````textreg = text.replace(new RegExp(/(\s)*[\:]([^\S\n\r])*/g,'g'),": ")```` do what I need